# What is this plant and how should I be taking care of it?

Tags: identification, houseplants, plant-care

I'm not sure how to even google this, so I'm hoping someone can identify it here.  It's probably a very common house plant, I'm just not too familiar with this one.  Watering it too much seems to be bad, but watering it too little isnt good but is also not killing it

[image: mystery plant photo 1]

Comment: does that pot have drainage?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Dracena marginata...you have to get this plant in a pot with drainage and potting soil.  It is slowly dying from too much water, no air and have you used fertilizer at all?  Just a little, Osmocote 14-14-14 at half the amount would be good.  Potting soil, not garden soil.  No other additives. Lift the bottom of the pot to get the best drainage.

Comment: I'm not sure there's drainage at all, looks like a glass bowl. It needs a proper pot with drainage holes for sure.

Comment: No, there is no drainage, I believe it came in that bowl in a Gift basket or something... but probably (or obviously) not meant to stay there.  I'm glad it has survived as long as it has!

Comment: As plants go, these are pretty tough, fortunately!

Answer (score 5):

Welcome to the forum Michael!

It's a dracena, though I'm not sure of the species (and it probably matters little for care).
A quick google of [dracena care](https://www.gardeningknowhow.com/houseplants/dracaena/dracaena-houseplant-care.htm) gave me this site.  Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks Ben!  First thing I'll do is get a new pot with drainage, thanks for the link!